# println() across multiple threads causes mixed messages

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, println

So this is becoming a big problem. Whenever I call println across multiple threads, it's mixing my messages up with eachother, giving me results such as this:

```
aeNdtedwt owbrolkro kcM kaM natanoga egarer:rr :aa yda:dd  d(b Flbuolncockct kit ootn o)a 
rarraryaN:ye :t( wF(ouFrnukcn tcMitaoinnoa)ng
)e
```

I'm wondering the best way to avoid this? Always call it from the main thread? Use NSLog instead?

Comment: NSLog is thread safe. Else you need to use GCD or as suggested the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this one

```
let delayTimeOne = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                                      Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

let delayTimeTwo = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                                      Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

let delayTimeThree = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                                      Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTimeOne, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("test1")
}

dispatch_after(delayTimeTwo, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("test2")
}

dispatch_after(delayTimeThree, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("test3")
}

// output
// test1
// test2
// test3
```